# How to disable the calendar attendant/assistant in Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013

In Microsoft Exchange, the "calendar attendant" automatically accepts invitations, updates them and removes invitation emails. I don't want to use it.

How to disable the calendar attendant in Microsoft Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the calendar attendant can be done by setting the `AutomateProcessing` parameter. However, changing this parameter **is only supported for shared resources** (rooms, equipments, ...).

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "user name" | Set-CalendarProcessing -AutomateProcessing:'none'
```

For regular user mailboxes, this is NOT possible anymore. It was previously supported with Exchange 2007 & 2010 and even for Exchange 2013 itself prior to CU7. See [Microsoft support answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b44b8a2d-1cdd-44ab-944c-21a2d276f228/how-to-disable-the-calendar-attendant-in-microsoft-exchange-2013?forum=exchangesvrgeneral#b44b8a2d-1cdd-44ab-944c-21a2d276f228)